# Film Response to light exposure. What is the explicit form of this recursive formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was intrigued by this talk about the Quanta Image Sensor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ZSoQgDrOM&t=2314s
And started playing around with the idea of film like response to light. I have made a simulation in python. **After a while of brainstorming I managed to find a recursive formula which represents the simulation well. However now I would like an explicit formula to calculate the individual values directly but don't know how to convert it from recursive to explicit form.**

$$V(n)=V(n-1)+\left(1-\frac{V(n-1)}{J}\right)$$

V is the current value, it starts at zero.
J is the number of "Jots" which have only two states either exposed or not. n is the current step index which starts at 1 in the formula, in the simulation n is replaced by i which starts at zero because computers...

I have also found that if the output values are scaled from 0 to 1 this formula seems to get close:

$$V(i)=-\left(\frac{1}{J}\right)^{i/t}+1$$

If instead of J a value smaller than J is input it gets closer. But I don't know if it can match exactly.

Here is the python code:

````
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    runs = 10  # reduce noise by averaging the results
    j = 1000   # number of jots
    t = 6000   # number of steps on the x-axis
    sim = np.zeros(t)
    rec = np.zeros(t)
    exp = np.zeros(t)

    # simulate film response by randomly exposing jots with photons
    for run in range(0, runs):
        jots = np.zeros(j)

        c = np.zeros(t)
        for i in range(1, t):
            jots[random.randint(0, j - 1)] = 1
            c[i] = jots.sum()
        sim += c / runs

    # calculate the values recursively instead of simulating
    v = 0
    for i in range(0, t):
        rec[i] = v
        v = v + (1 - (v / j))

    # nice try
    for i in range(0, t):
        exp[i] = -((1 / j) ** (i / t)) + 1
    exp *= j

    # display the results with matplotlib
    plt.plot(sim, label="simulation")
    plt.plot(rec, label="recursive formula")
    plt.plot(exp, label="nice try")
    plt.semilogx(base=2)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```
````

Comment: Is $J$ constant?

Comment: I think of it as a variable, the more jots there are the smoother the simulation approximation is. But also instead of adding more jots it's possible to increase the number of runs to smooth out the result. if J is increased in the simulation t should increase proportionally to give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $W_n=V_n - J$ satisfies the recursion $$W_{n+1} = (1-J^{-1}) W_n$$ and therefore $$ W_n = (1-J^{-1})^n W_0$$ or
$$ V_n = (1-J^{-1})^n(V_0-J) + J.$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Did you arrive that from pure intuition? What math would one need to learn to understand?

Comment: I see now that this solution is quite similar to my attempt above.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes $J$ is constant, which seems true from your code, though I don't know much Python. You can solve similar recursive problems this same way, though this is not necessarily the easiest solution.

The recursive formula can be written as $$V(n)=V(n-1)(1-\frac1{J})+1$$. Multiply by $x^n$ to get $$V(n)x^n=V(n-1)x^n\cdot(1-\frac1{J})+x^n$$
Sum all over $n>1$:
$$\sum_{n>1}V(n)x^n=(1-\frac1{J})\sum_{n>1}V(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n>1}x^n~~\text{(1)}$$
Now denote $S(x)=\sum_{n>1}V(n)x^n$. It follows that $\sum_{n>1}V(n-1)x^n=x\sum_{n>1}V(n-1)x^{n-1}=x(S(x)-V(1)x)=xS(x)$. Finally $\sum_{n>1}x^n=\frac1{1-x}-1-x$(geometric series but it starts at 2 instead of $0$). Now substitute all of these in $(1)$, noting $a=1-\frac1{J}$:
$$S(x)=axS(x)+\frac1{1-x}-1-x$$.
Solving for $S(x)$ gets us:
$$S(x)=\frac{\frac1{1-x}-1-x}{1-ax}$$
Now we want to find a power series for the right side. With the help of Wolfram Alpha, we get the following series:
$$S(x)=\sum_{n>1}x^n\frac{1-a^{n-1}}{1-a}$$
This can be obtained manually by doing partial fraction decomposition. Finally, since $S(x)=\sum_{n>1}V(n)x^n$, it follows that $V(n)=\frac{1-a^{n-1}}{1-a}$. This seems to hold for $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! What math would one need to learn to understand how you arrive at the solution?

Comment: You need to learn a few things about power series. This method is called generating functions. There's a pretty good book about it named Generating Functionology by Herbert Wilf. For this particular problem though, WimC's solution is definitely simpler!